# Is it possible to map a discontiuous data on disk to an array with python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran, hdf5

I want to map a big fortran record (12G) on hard disk to a numpy array. (Mapping instead of loading for saving memory.)

The data stored in fortran record is not continuous as it is divided by record markers. The record structure is as "marker, data, marker, data,..., data, marker". The length of data regions and markers are known.

The length of data between markers is not multiple of 4 bytes, otherwise I can map each data region to an array.

The first marker can be skipped by setting offset in memmap, is it possible to skip other markers and map the data to an array?

Apology for possible ambiguous expression and thanks for any solution or suggestion.

---

Edited May 15

These are fortran unformatted files. The data stored in record is a (1024^3)*3 float32 array (12Gb).

The record layout of variable-length records that are greater than 2 gigabytes is shown below:

[image: data structure]

(For details see [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-win/index.htm#GUID-64D43E4C-68E7-4C48-8B50-B49F1F7DA46C.htm) -> the section [Record Types] -> [Variable-Length Records].)

In my case, except the last one, each subrecord has a length  of 2147483639 bytes and separated by 8 bytes (as you see in the figure above, a end marker of the previous subrecord and a begin marker of the following one, 8 bytes in total ) .

We can see the first subrecord ends with the first 3 bytes of certain float number and the second subrecord begins with the rest 1 byte as 2147483639 mod 4 =3.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more details about the data structure?  Based on what I think you're saying, you have variable-length arrays between your markers? How are they packed (e.g. float, int8, int16, whatever)?

Comment: Thanks for attention and sorry for lack of details. More imformation is added. I'm trying h5py as suggested by Castro.

Comment: Sorry, I fogot to notify you @JoeKington.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted another answer because for [the example given here](http://notepad.cc/share/vqfe8y5D4G) `numpy.memmap` worked:

```
offset = 0
data1 = np.memmap('tmp', dtype='i', mode='r+', order='F',
                  offset=0, shape=(size1))
offset += size1*byte_size
data2 = np.memmap('tmp', dtype='i', mode='r+', order='F',
                  offset=offset, shape=(size2))
offset += size1*byte_size
data3 = np.memmap('tmp', dtype='i', mode='r+', order='F',
                  offset=offset, shape=(size3))
```

for `int32` `byte_size=32/8`, for `int16` `byte_size=16/8` and so forth...

If the sizes are constant, you can load the data in a 2D array like:

```
shape = (total_length/size,size)
data = np.memmap('tmp', dtype='i', mode='r+', order='F', shape=shape)
```

You can change the `memmap` object as long as you want. It is even possible to make arrays sharing the same elements. In that case the changes made in one are automatically updated in the other.

Other references:

- [Working with big data in python and numpy, not enough ram, how to save partial results on disc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633274/832621)
- [`numpy.memmap` documentation here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html#numpy.memmap).

Comment: I can access the 12GB file with memmap without any error. However, two problem remain. The first is the endian. order='F' is for 2D (or higher) array storing order not for the endian, so I have to do extra endian switch. The second the markers is mixed with the data， I have no idea to pick out the markers. Maybe my discription about the question is not clear.

Comment: Or I can use shape and offset to read the first subrecord of the file, question remains -- how can I put several subrecord together? I'm sorry for the poor expression in English.

Comment: Endian problem is solved, just set dtype with '>' i.e. test = np.memmap(file_path, dtype='>i', mode='r', order='F')

Comment: @substructure if you consider this solution satisfactory already, you can toggle it as accepted

Comment: Many thanks for you help. I'm afraid the main question remains -- is it possible to map the data (markers excluded) to an array. Now I can map the whole file to an array but the data and the markers are still interlaced. It's not convenient to do indexing for the pure data.

Comment: @substructure Please, I've included some more info in the answer that might be useful for handling the discontinuous data structure that you have