# Share Large, Read-Only Numpy Array Between Multiprocessing Processes

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a 60GB SciPy Array (Matrix) I must share between 5+ `multiprocessing` `Process` objects. I've seen numpy-sharedmem and read [this discussion](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/1144s75ps4/multiprocessing-shared-memory-vs-pickled-copies) on the SciPy list. There seem to be two approaches--`numpy-sharedmem` and using a `multiprocessing.RawArray()` and mapping NumPy `dtype`s to `ctype`s. Now, `numpy-sharedmem` seems to be the way to go, but I've yet to see a good reference example. I don't need any kind of locks, since the array (actually a matrix) will be read-only. Now, due to its size, I'd like to avoid a copy. It *sounds like* the correct method is to create the *only* copy of the array as a `sharedmem` array, and then pass it to the `Process` objects? A couple of specific questions:

1. What's the best way to actually pass the sharedmem handles to sub-`Process()`es? Do I need a queue just to pass one array around? Would a pipe be better? Can I just pass it as an argument to the `Process()` subclass's init (where I'm assuming it's pickled)?
2. In the discussion I linked above, there's mention of `numpy-sharedmem` not being 64bit-safe? I'm definitely using some structures that aren't 32-bit addressable.
3. Are there tradeoff's to the `RawArray()` approach? Slower, buggier?
4. Do I need any ctype-to-dtype mapping for the numpy-sharedmem method?
5. Does anyone have an example of some OpenSource code doing this? I'm a very hands-on learned and it's hard to get this working without any kind of good example to look at.

If there's any additional info I can provide to help clarify this for others, please comment and I'll add. Thanks!

This needs to run on Ubuntu Linux and *Maybe* Mac OS, but portability isn't a huge concern.

Comment: If the different processes are going to write to that array, expect `multiprocessing` to make a copy of the whole thing for each process.

Comment: @tiago: "I don't need any kind of locks, since the array (actually a matrix) will be read-only"

Comment: @tiago: also, multiprocessing is not making a copy as long as not explicitly told to (via arguments to the `target_function`). The operating system is going to copy parts of the parent's memory to the child's memory space upon modification only.

Comment: here's [a RawArray-based example that should work both on *nix and Windows, and it also supports writing to the array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7908612/4279).

Comment: I asked a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705974/why-are-multiprocessing-sharedctypes-assignments-so-slow) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566404/assertion-error-when-using-multiprocessing-in-python-3-4) about this before. My solution can be found here: https://github.com/david-hoffman/peaks/blob/3a2c1c39119388a8996cdd510524a48ee5d7907d/stackanalysis.py#L85-L108 (sorry the code is a disaster).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

@Velimir Mlaker gave a great answer. I thought I could add some bits of comments and a tiny example.

(I couldn't find much documentation on sharedmem - these are the results of my own experiments.)

1. Do you need to pass the handles when the subprocess is starting, or after it has started? If it's just the former, you can just use the `target` and `args` arguments for `Process`. This is potentially better than using a global variable.
2. From the discussion page you linked, it appears that support for 64-bit Linux was added to sharedmem a while back, so it could be a non-issue.
3. I don't know about this one.
4. No. Refer to example below.

#### Example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process
import sharedmem
import numpy

def do_work(data, start):
    data[start] = 0;

def split_work(num):
    n = 20
    width  = n/num
    shared = sharedmem.empty(n)
    shared[:] = numpy.random.rand(1, n)[0]
    print "values are %s" % shared

    processes = [Process(target=do_work, args=(shared, i*width)) for i in xrange(num)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print "values are %s" % shared
    print "type is %s" % type(shared[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    split_work(4)
```

#### Output

```
values are [ 0.81397784  0.59667692  0.10761908  0.6736734   0.46349645  0.98340718
  0.44056863  0.10701816  0.67167752  0.29158274  0.22242552  0.14273156
  0.34912309  0.43812636  0.58484507  0.81697513  0.57758441  0.4284959
  0.7292129   0.06063283]
values are [ 0.          0.59667692  0.10761908  0.6736734   0.46349645  0.
  0.44056863  0.10701816  0.67167752  0.29158274  0.          0.14273156
  0.34912309  0.43812636  0.58484507  0.          0.57758441  0.4284959
  0.7292129   0.06063283]
type is <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing) might be useful.

Answer (score 46):

If you are on Linux (or any POSIX-compliant system), you can define this array as a global variable. `multiprocessing` is using `fork()` on Linux when it starts a new child process. A newly spawned child process automatically shares the memory with its parent as long as it does not change it ([copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) mechanism).

Since you are saying "I don't need any kind of locks, since the array (actually a matrix) will be read-only" taking advantage of this behavior would be a very simple and yet extremely efficient approach: all child processes will access the same data in physical memory when reading this large numpy array.

Don't hand your array to the `Process()` constructor, this will instruct `multiprocessing` to `pickle` the data to the child, which would be extremely inefficient or impossible in your case. On Linux, right after `fork()` the child is an exact copy of the parent using the same physical memory, so all you need to do is making sure that the Python variable 'containing' the matrix is accessible from within the `target` function that you hand over to `Process()`. This you can typically achieve with a 'global' variable.

Example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from numpy import random


global_array = random.random(10**4)


def child():
    print sum(global_array)


def main():
    processes = [Process(target=child) for _ in xrange(10)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

On Windows -- which does not support `fork()` -- `multiprocessing` is using the win32 API call `CreateProcess`. It creates an entirely new process from any given executable. That's why on Windows one is *required* to pickle data to the child if one needs data that has been created during runtime of the parent.

Comment: Thanks, but, doesn't referencecounting force a copy? I know how copy-on-write works in a C program, but how can I guarantee there are no "writes"? I feel like I need some kind of shared memory here.

Comment: Copy-on-write will copy the page containing the reference counter (so each forked python will have its own reference counter) but it will not copy the whole data array.

Comment: I would add that I've had more success with module level variables than with global variables... ie add the variable to a module in global scope before the fork

Comment: A word of caution to people stumbling across this question/answer: If you happen to be using OpenBLAS-linked Numpy for its multithreadead operation, make sure to disable its multithreading (export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1) when using `multiprocessing` or child processes might end up hanging (typically using 1/n of _one_ processor rather than n processors) upon performing linear algebra operations on a shared global array/matrix. The [known multithreaded conflict with OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/faq#wiki-multi-threaded) seems to extend to Python `multiprocessing`

Comment: Can anyone explain why python wouldn't just use OS `fork` to pass parameters given to `Process`, instead of serializing them? That is, couldn't the `fork` be applied to the parent process just *before* `child` is called, so that the parameter value is still available from the OS? Would seem to be more efficient than serializing it?

Comment: @max providing a common interface on top of very different platforms (Windows and POSIX are *very* different in terms of process creation) requires making compromises. Here, I guess, the compromise is to use the *same* method of parameter transfer on both platforms by default, for better maintainability and for ensuring equal behavior. Nevertheless, if you are aware of it, you can take advantage of POSIX fork() yourself, as I proposed in this answer. This is not difficult at all, so there is no particular "need" for multiprocessing to support it.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke python only supports the `fork` method under POSIX, so compatibility isn't an issue.

Comment: @max I guess you do not really know what you are writing about, and now I am entirely confused and cannot really help. I try anyway: `fork()` is a system call, which is something that the operating system has to provide. Python, or any other application, can *use* it. Windows does not provide `fork()`. So, *"python only supports the fork method under POSIX"* is half wrong and half obvious, and *"compatibility isn't an issue"* tells me nothing about what you are struggling with now. It *is* an issue, considering that Windows does not support `fork()`.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I meant that I'm asking about `'fork'`, which is one of several start methods supported by python's `multiprocessing.Process`, and which is documented as only supported under POSIX; you can't use it on Windows at all. So Python is not constrained by any cross-platform issues when using `'fork'` start method. My question was why in this situation, Python wouldn't call the `target` function and then `os.fork()` instead of `fork`ing before the call and therefore serializing the argument to `target`.

Comment: We are all aware of that `fork()` is not available on Windows, it has been stated in my answer and multiple times in the comments. I know that this was your initial question, and I answered it four comments above *this*: "the compromise is to use the same method of parameter transfer on both platforms by default, for better maintainability and for ensuring equal behavior.". Both ways have their advantages and disadvantages, which is why in Python 3 there is greater flexibility for the user to choose the method. This discussion is not productive w/o talking details, which we should not do here.

Comment: What about the `global` keyword, is it required?

Answer (score 26):

You may be interested in a tiny piece of code I wrote: [github.com/vmlaker/benchmark-sharedmem](https://github.com/vmlaker/benchmark-sharedmem)

The only file of interest is `main.py`. It's a benchmark of [numpy-sharedmem](https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem) -- the code simply passes arrays (either `numpy` or `sharedmem`) to spawned processes, via Pipe. The workers just call `sum()` on the data. I was only interested in comparing the data communication times between the two implementations.

I also wrote another, more complex code: [github.com/vmlaker/sherlock](https://github.com/vmlaker/sherlock).

Here I use the [numpy-sharedmem](https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem) module for real-time image processing with OpenCV -- the images are NumPy arrays, as per OpenCV's newer `cv2` API. The images, actually references thereof, are shared between processes via the dictionary object created from [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) (as opposed to using Queue or Pipe.) I'm getting great performance improvements when compared with using plain NumPy arrays.

**Pipe vs. Queue**:

In my experience, IPC with Pipe is faster than Queue. And that makes sense, since Queue adds locking to make it safe for multiple producers/consumers. Pipe doesn't. But if you only have two processes talking back-and-forth, it's safe to use Pipe, or, as the docs read:

> ... there is no risk of corruption from processes using different ends of the pipe at the same time.

**`sharedmem` safety**:

The main issue with `sharedmem` module is the possibility of memory leak upon ungraceful program exit. This is described in a lengthy discussion [here](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/1144s75ps4/multiprocessing-shared-memory-vs-pickled-copies). Although on Apr 10, 2011 Sturla mentions a fix to memory leak, I have still experienced leaks since then, using both repos, Sturla Molden's own on GitHub ([github.com/sturlamolden/sharedmem-numpy](https://github.com/sturlamolden/sharedmem-numpy)) and Chris Lee-Messer's on Bitbucket ([bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem](https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem)).

Comment: Thanks, very very informative. The memory leak in `sharedmem` sounds like a big deal, though. Any leads on solving that?

Comment: Beyond just noticing the leaks, I haven't looked for it in the code. I added to my answer, under "sharedmem safety" above, keepers of the two open source repos of the ``sharedmem`` module, for reference.

Answer (score 18):

If your array is that big you can use `numpy.memmap`. For example, if you have an array stored in disk, say `'test.array'`, you can use simultaneous processes to access the data in it even in "writing" mode, but your case is simpler since you only need "reading" mode.

Creating the array:

```
a = np.memmap('test.array', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(100000,1000))
```

You can then fill this array in the same way you do with an ordinary array. For example:

```
a[:10,:100]=1.
a[10:,100:]=2.
```

The data is stored into disk when you delete the variable `a`.

Later on you can use multiple processes that will access the data in `test.array`:

```
# read-only mode
b = np.memmap('test.array', dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(100000,1000))

# read and writing mode
c = np.memmap('test.array', dtype='float32', mode='r+', shape=(100000,1000))
```

Related answers:

- [Working with big data in python and numpy, not enough ram, how to save partial results on disc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633274/832621)
- [Is it possible to map a discontiuous data on disk to an array with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597695/832621)

Comment: So in this case, all processes will be able to access the same `np.memmap` object without replication, and without having to somehow pass the object?

Answer (score 3):

You may also find it useful to take a look at the documentation for [pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) as if you can partition your task appropriately you could use it to execute different sections on different machines as well as on different cores in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use multithreading?
Resources of main process can be shared by its threads natively, thus multithreading is obviously a better way to share objects owned by the main process.

If you worry about python's GIL mechanism, maybe you can resort to the [`nogil`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#nogil) of `numba`.