# passing numpy arrays through multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm using `multiprocessing.Queue` to pass numpy arrays of `float64` between python processes. This is working fine, but I'm worried it may not be as efficient as it could be.

According to the documentation of `multiprocessing`, objects placed on the `Queue` will be pickled. calling `pickle` on a numpy array results in a text representation of the data, so null bytes get replaced by the string `"\\x00"`.

`>>> pickle.dumps(numpy.zeros(10))`
`"cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np0\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np1\n(I0\ntp2\nS'b'\np3\ntp4\nRp5\n(I1\n(I10\ntp6\ncnumpy\ndtype\np7\n(S'f8'\np8\nI0\nI1\ntp9\nRp10\n(I3\nS'<'\np11\nNNNI-1\nI-1\nI0\ntp12\nbI00\nS'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\np13\ntp14\nb."`

I'm concerned that this means my arrays are being expensively converted into something 4x the original size and then converted back in the other process.

Is there a way to pass the data through the queue in a raw unaltered form?

I know about shared memory, but if that is the correct solution, I'm not sure how to build a queue on top of it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can zip it before sending zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(numpy.zeros(10)))

Comment: Thanks. That would indeed make it smaller, but in this case I'm actually more concerned about the CPU usage. I would like to avoid the work of computing the pickling. Adding an additional compress step would make it even slower, right? Ideally I'd want to just have the array stored in shared memory and let the other process access it directly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes

that should cover it all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with numpy, but the default settings for how [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) represents data (as strings so the output is human readable).  You can [change the default settings for pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) to produce binary data instead.

```
import numpy
import cPickle as pickle

N = 1000
a0 = pickle.dumps(numpy.zeros(N))
a1 = pickle.dumps(numpy.zeros(N), protocol=-1)

print "a0", len(a0)   # 32155
print "a1", len(a1)   #  8133
```

Also, note, that if you want to decrease processor work and time, you should probably use `cPickle` instead of pickle (but the space savings due to using the binary protocol work regardless of pickle version).

On shared memory:
On the question of shared memory, there are a few things to consider.  Shared data typically adds a significant amount of complexity to code.  Basically, for every line of code that uses that data, you will need to worry about whether some other line of code in another process is simultaneously using that data.  How hard this will be will depend on what you're doing.  The advantages are that you save time sending the data back and forth.  The question that Eelco cites is for a 60GB array, and for this there's really no choice, it has to be shared.  On the other hand, for most reasonably complex code, deciding to share data simply to save a few microseconds or bytes would probably be one of the worst premature optimizations one could make.

Answer (score 4):

[Share Large, Read-Only Numpy Array Between Multiprocessing Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes)

That should cover it all. Pickling of uncompressible binary data is a pain regardless of the protocol used, so this solution is much to be preferred.

Comment: that and http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/1144s75ps4/multiprocessing-shared-memory-vs-pickled-copies (referenced in your link)