# How to use custom data structure with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-structures, multiprocessing

I'm using python 2.7 and numpy on a linux machine.
I am running a program which involves a time-consuming function `computeGP(level, grid)` which takes input in form of a numpy array `level` and an object `grid`, which is not is not modified by this function.

My goal is to parallelize `computeGP` (locally, so on different cores) for different `level` but the same `grid`. Since `grid` stays invariant, this can be done without synchronization hassle using shared memory. [I've read a bit about threading in python and the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135569/3550459) and it seems to me that i should go with the `multiprocessing` module rather than threading. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724332/3550459) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing/5550156#5550156) answers recommend to use `multiprocessing.Array` to share efficiently, while noting that on unix machines it is default behaviour that the object is not copied.

**My problem** is that the object `grid` is not a numpy array. 
It is a list of numpy arrays, because the way my data structure works is that i need to access array (listelement) *N* and then access its row *K*.
Basically the list just fakes pointers to the arrays.

So my questions are:

1. My understanding is, that on unix machines i can share the object
   `grid` without any further usage of `multiprocessing` datatypes
   `Array` (or `Value`). Is that correct?
2. Is there a better way to
   implement this pointer-to-array datastructure which can use the more
   efficient `multiprocessing.Array`?

I don't want to assemble one large array containing the smaller ones from the list, because the smaller ones are not really small either...

Any thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This SO question is very similar to yours: [Share Large, Read-Only Numpy Array Between Multiprocessing Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes)

There are a few answers in there, but the simplest *if you are only using linux* is to just make the data structure a global variable.  Linux will `fork()` the process, which gives all worker processes copy-on-write access to the main process' memory (globals).

In this case you don't need to use any special multiprocessing classes or pass any data to the worker processes except level.