# Assertion Error when using multiprocessing in Python 3.4

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm pretty new to Python and completely new to parallel processing.

I've been writing code to analyze punctate image data (think [PALM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_microscopy#STORM.2C_PALM_and_FPALM) lite) and trying to speed up my analysis code using the `multiprocessing` module.

For small data sets I see a pretty decent speed-up up to four cores. For large datasets I start getting an AssertionError. I tried to make a boiled down example which produces the same error, see below:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data

    def top_level_function(self, nproc = 1):

        if nproc > os.cpu_count():
            nproc = os.cpu_count()

        if nproc == 1:
            sums = [self._sub_function() for i in range(10)]
        elif 1 < nproc:
            print('multiprocessing engaged with {} cores'.format(nproc))
            with mp.Pool(nproc) as p:
                sums = [p.apply_async(self._sub_function) for i in range(10)]
                sums = [pp.get() for pp in sums]

        self.sums = sums

        return sums

    def _sub_function(self):
        return self.data.sum(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = TestClass(np.zeros((126,512,512)))
    ans = t.top_level_function()
    print(len(ans))
    ans = t.top_level_function(4)
    print(len(ans))

    t = TestClass(np.zeros((126,2048,2048)))
    ans = t.top_level_function()
    print(len(ans))
    ans = t.top_level_function(4)
    print(len(ans))
```

which outputs:

```
10
multiprocessing engaged with 4 cores
10
10
multiprocessing engaged with 4 cores
Process SpawnPoolWorker-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 355, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 318, in _recv_bytes
    return self._get_more_data(ov, maxsize)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 337, in _get_more_data
    assert left > 0
AssertionError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 355, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 318, in _recv_bytes
    return self._get_more_data(ov, maxsize)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 337, in _get_more_data
    assert left > 0
AssertionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 41, in <module>
    ans = t.top_level_function(4)
  File "test.py", line 21, in top_level_function
    sums = [pp.get() for pp in sums]
  File "test.py", line 21, in <listcomp>
    sums = [pp.get() for pp in sums]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 383, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

So the first example runs fine, but the later example (larger set of data) crashes.

I'm pretty lost about where this error is coming from and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, the first (`t = TestClass(np.zeros((126,512,512)))`) works with no error while the second (`t = TestClass(np.zeros((126,2048,2048)))`) results in the error you described?

Comment: As mata explained, you probably have too much data being sent between processes. Each process should probably be loading data itself, doing as much processing as reasonable and returning some kind of small-size result. Basically minimize the amount of data sent between processes. If you can explain more about the data inputs, intermediates, functions and outputs, then someone might suggest a better arrangement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
sums = [p.apply_async(self._sub_function) for i in range(10)]
```

what happens is that `self._sub_function` will be pickled 10 times and sent to a worker process to be processed. To pickle an instance method, the whole instance (*including* the `data` attribute) has to be pickled. A quick check shows that `np.zeros((126,2048,2048))` when pickled requires 4227858596 bytes, and you're sending 10 times that, to 10 different processes.

You're getting a error during `_send_bytes`, which means the transfer to the worker process was interrupted, my guess would be because you're hitting your memory limit.

You should probably rethink your design, multiprocessing usually works best if each worker can work on part of the problem without needing access to the whole data.

Comment: agreed on this one. This: `winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)` yielding a windows error looks like windows is puking on some IO and this is a lot of pickling.