# Python multiprocessing - How can I split workload to get speed improvement?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, opencv3.0

I am writing a simple code of cropping images and saving it.
But the problem is that the number of images is about 150,000+ and I want to improve the speed.

So, at first I wrote a code with simple for loops, like the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy
import sys

textfile=sys.argv[1]
file_list=open(textfile)
files=file_list.read().split('\n')
idx=0
for eachfile in files:
    image=cv2.imread(eachfile)
    idx+=1
    if image is None:
        pass
    outName=eachfile.replace('/data','/changed_data')
    if image.shape[0]==256:
        image1=image[120:170,120:170]
    elif image.shape[0]==50:
        image1=image
    cv2.imwrite(outName,image1)
    print idx,outName
```

This code took about 38 seconds for 90000 images.
But, using dual core took more time than single process, about 48 seconds for the same 90000 images.

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy
from multiprocessing import Pool

def crop(eachfile):
    image=cv2.imread(eachfile)
    idx+=1
    if image is None:
        pass
    outName=eachfile.replace('/data','/changed_data')
    if image.shape[0]==256:
        image1=image[120:170,120:170]
    elif image.shape[0]==50:
        image1=image
    cv2.imwrite(outName,image1)
    print idx,outName


if __name__=='__main__':
    textfile=sys.argv[1]
    file_list=open(textfile)
    files=file_list.read().split('\n')
    pool=Pool(2)
    pool.map(crop,files)
```

Am I doing the right thing for speeding up the process? Or should I split the list and send each list to the process?

Any comments regard my code would be great!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: btw, the program is reading text file with files seperated by \n characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed split the task over two cores. Play around with this example code "slightly modified". OP can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking). Where you see `data` that is your hook providing your images. The defs don't work under class when using `multiprocessing`... If your trying to use pathos...you'll get errors from cPickle... some nagging issue with latest 2.7 version. Doesn't occur in 3.5 or something. Enjoy!

```
import multiprocessing

def mp_worker((inputs, the_time)):
    print " Process %s\tWaiting %s seconds" % (inputs, the_time)
    time.sleep(int(the_time))
    print " Process %s\tDONE" % inputs
    sys.stdout.flush()

def mp_handler():                           # Non tandem pair processing
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(mp_worker, data)

def mp_handler_tandem():
    subdata = zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])
#    print subdata
    for task1, task2 in subdata:
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
        p.map(mp_worker, (task1, task2))

#data = (['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3'], ['d', '4'])
data = (['a', '2'], ['b', '3'], ['c', '1'], ['d', '4'], 
        ['e', '1'], ['f', '2'], ['g', '3'], ['h', '4'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout.flush()
#    print 'mp_handler():'
#    mp_handler()
#    print '---'
#    time.sleep(2)

#    print '\nmp_handler_tandem():'
#    mp_handler_tandem()
    print '---'
#    time.sleep(2)

    Multiprocess().qmp_handler()
```

> working within an editor: use `sys.stdout.flush()` to flush your output to screen while it happens.

But check also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33195411/8928024) using kernels and splitting jobs.