# Shared numpy array with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a numpy array(matrix), which I want to fill with calculated values in asynchronously. As a result, I want to have matrix distances with calculated values, but at the end I receive matrix filled with default(-1) value. I understand, that something wrong with sharing distances between threads, but I can't figure out what's exactly wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures

data = range(1, 10)
amount = len(data)
default = -1
distances = np.full((amount, amount), default, dtype=np.float32)


def calculate_distance(i, j):
    global distances
    if i == j:
        distances[i][j] = 0
    else:
        calculated = data[i] + data[j] #doesn't matter how is this calculated
        distances[i][j] = calculated
        distances[j][i] = calculated


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(0, amount):
        for j in range(i, amount):
            future = executor.submit(calculate_distance, i, j)
            result = future.result()

executor.shutdown(True)
print(distances)
```

Comment: You're using processes, not threads. I take it that you're using an environment that supports forking. This means that you get processes that have a copy of `distances` (actually of the memory in general). When these processes modify `distances`, they modify their own copy. This is a simplification, as copy-on-write may be involved, but the end result is the same.

Comment: You might also be interested in this Q/A regarding read-only shared numpy arrays for use between processes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes.

Comment: First, when using the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, you need to include a `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard, otherwise your code won't work on all platforms.  Second, you wait for each task to finish before submitting the next one, so the tasks are executed seuqentially.  And third, using threads generally won't allow you to get more processor time for Python code due to the Global Interpreter Lock.

Comment: @SvenMarnach what should I use to execute tasks in a parallel way?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.  This will fork new processes for performing work.  These processes will not share memory, each instead getting a copy of the `distances` matrix.

Thus any changes to their *copy* will certainly not be reflected in the original process.

Try using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead.

**NOTE:** Globals are generally viewed with distaste ... pass the array into the function instead.