# Working with huge numpy arrays without loading the whole data on the disk

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, tensorflow

I have a large set of image patches, which I used to store inside a numpy array `[n_patchesxWxHx3]` (with `n_patches` being super large).

I need to perform the two following operations a certain number of times:

- First shuffle the indices of the patches
- Then, iterate through the set by producing each time `BATCH_SIZE` patches at a time   which I need once and then I can discard them

My approach was to use the one which can be found in TensorFlow repository (in `contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist`), which creates a huge numpy array and iterates on it with a `next_batch` method:

```
  def next_batch(self, batch_size, fake_data=False):
    """Return the next `batch_size` examples from this data set."""
    if fake_data:
      fake_image = [1] * 784
      if self.one_hot:
        fake_label = [1] + [0] * 9
      else:
        fake_label = 0
      return [fake_image for _ in xrange(batch_size)], [
          fake_label for _ in xrange(batch_size)
      ]
    start = self._index_in_epoch
    self._index_in_epoch += batch_size
    if self._index_in_epoch > self._num_examples:
      # Finished epoch
      self._epochs_completed += 1
      # Shuffle the data
      perm = numpy.arange(self._num_examples)
      numpy.random.shuffle(perm)
      self._images = self._images[perm]
      self._labels = self._labels[perm]
      # Start next epoch
      start = 0
      self._index_in_epoch = batch_size
      assert batch_size <= self._num_examples
    end = self._index_in_epoch
    return self._images[start:end], self._labels[start:end]
```

(This code is not mine - it was written by the TF team)

I know of TensorFlow binary format `.tfrecords`, but I would like to have access each time to Python objects (numpy arrays if possible or something that can be parsed without TF). I was wondering if there was a Pythonic way to use the same method but to load in the memory only the current patches.

**EDIT 1:** What would be neat if even possible is to iterate on a binary file and be able to convert a specific zone of it to a numpy array, something similar to tfrecords...

**EDIT 2:** Following the remark of @user6758673 I think the idea that I had is actually implemented in `memmap` I found the related issue [using memmap for batch processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242911/using-memmap-files-for-batch-processing) however interacting with memmap seems to be troublesome gonna try. This thread made me wonder does something like this also exist in `hdf5` ? It seems scikitlearn repo is a good place to start digging...

**EDIT 3:** It seems I am not the first guy to run into the same issue, great discussion here on [Lasagne repo](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/issues/615)

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.memmap` and `numpy.load(..., mmap_mode='r')`

Comment: memmap looks promising ! Thanks ! gonna look into that !