# how to load a big train.csv for XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

The `train.csv` is about 90G.

It like:

```
label,col1,col2,col3,col4......col400
0,0.92,-0.69,-0.13,0.01.......,0.22
1,0.22,-0.39,0.11,0.92........,-0.43
```

my code like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

train=pd.read_csv('/home/data/train.csv')
test=pd.read_csv('/home/data/test.csv')
params = {
    'booster': 'gbtree',
    'objective': 'multi:softmax',
    'num_class': 10,  
    'gamma': 0.1,  
    'max_depth': 12,
    'lambda': 2,  
    'subsample': 0.7,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.7,
    'min_child_weight': 3,
    'silent': 1,
    'eta': 0.007,
    'seed': 1000,
}
plst = list(params.items())
num_rounds = 100
train_xy, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
y = train_xy.label
X = train_xy.drop(['label'], axis=1)
val_y = val.label
val_X = val.drop(['label'], axis=1)

xgb_val = xgb.DMatrix(val_X, label=val_y)
xgb_train = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y)
xgb_test = xgb.DMatrix(tests)

watchlist = [(xgb_train, 'train'), (xgb_val, 'val')]

# training model 

start_time = time.time()
model = xgb.train(plst, xgb_train, num_rounds, watchlist, early_stopping_rounds=100)
print(time.time() - start_time)
plst = list(params.items())
num_rounds = 100
train_xy, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
y = train_xy.label
X = train_xy.drop(['label'], axis=1)
val_y = val.label
val_X = val.drop(['label'], axis=1)

xgb_val = xgb.DMatrix(val_X, label=val_y)
xgb_train = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y)
xgb_test = xgb.DMatrix(tests)

watchlist = [(xgb_train, 'train'), (xgb_val, 'val')]

# training model 

start_time = time.time()
model = xgb.train(plst, xgb_train, num_rounds, watchlist, early_stopping_rounds=100)
print(time.time() - start_time)
model.save_model('./model/xgb.model')
```

Can I divide this csv into several parts?  Or increase the virtual memory?

Comment: have you considered mapping it like suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16633274/3512538

Comment: Great! I think it will be work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @K.Alan Did it actually work. As far as I understand for XGboost you have to load data into DMatrix (memory).