# How does the model in sklearn handle large data sets in python?

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

Now I have 10GB of data set to train the model in sklearn, but my computer only has 8GB of memory, so I have other ways to go besides incremental classifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think sklearn can be used for larger data if the technique is right. If your chosen algorithms support partial_fit or an online learning approach then you're on track. The chunk_size may influence your success

This link may be useful( [Working with big data in python and numpy, not enough ram, how to save partial results on the disc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r?lq=1))

Another thing you can do is to randomly pick whether or not to keep a row in your csv file...and save the result to a .npy file so it loads quicker. That way you get a sampling of your data that will allow you to start playing with it with all algorithms...and deal with the bigger data issue along the way(or not at all! sometimes a sample with a good approach is good enough depending on what you want).