# Python: numpy memmap in parallel

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi, memmap

Does it make sense to use numpy's **`memmap`** across multiple cores (MPI)?

I have a file on disk.

Can I create a separate **`memmap`** object on each core, and use it to read different slices from the file?

What about writing to it?

Comment: Could you describe your application in a bit more detail? Also, there is a pretty helpful answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r/16633274#16633274

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Does it make sense to use numpy's `memmap` across multiple cores (MPI)?"*

Yes <sub>*( ... even without MPI, using just Python native { thread- | process-}-based forms of concurrent-processing )*</sub>

> **Q** : *"Can I create a separate `memmap`-object on each core, and use it to read different slices from the file?"*

Yes.

> **Q** : *"What about writing to it?"*

The same *<sub>( sure, if having been opened in write-able mode ... )</sub>*