# How to convert Python list to Numpy arrays Efficiently(batch by batch?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I had a big problem with python lists and NumPy arrays. I want to convert my python list to NumPy arrays but list are so big that ram cannot handle them. So is there a method that does this job batch by batch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with big data in python and numpy, not enough ram, how to save partial results on disc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r)

Comment: What do you intend to do with the array(s)?

Comment: i used arrays for machine learning. The model expect to have np arrays as type of input

Comment: Some machine-learning packages have a way of defining inputs as batches.  For home-brewed `numpy` based learning we can't help without details.

Comment: the model can handle batches but data has a type of python list. first I have to convert python lists(data) to np arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the split method from the

[Splitting a list into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length)

and this is the function from the link above:

```
def split(a, n):
   k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
   return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))
```

This should work

```
import numpy as np

 
def split(a, n):
   k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
   return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))

for i in (list(split(yourList,n))):
    print(np.array(i))
```

This should print out the split np arrays

##### Remember that you need to split the list equally

Comment: No Problem. Thanks for your kind comment!

Comment: Wait can you check this answer as correct so that people do not misunderstand that this is a unsolved question.