# How can I perform XOR between every elements of two 2D numpy arrays by saving the memory usage efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation

I am not familiar with XOR operations and I was wondering if there is an efficient way to perform XOR operation for every elements between two 2D NumPy arrays by saving the memory usage.

Here is my toy example:

```
# Example arrays
u_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]])

v_values = np.array([[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True],
                     [True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
                     [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]])
```

Here is what I tried:

```
u_reshaped = u_values[:, None, :]
v_reshaped = v_values[None, :, :]
xor_result = u_reshaped ^ v_reshaped
xor_results = xor_result.reshape((-1, xor_result.shape[2]))
```

I even tried to use the *np.packbits* function to see if I can save the memory:

```
u_values_packed = np.packbits(u_values, axis=1)
v_values_packed = np.packbits(v_values, axis=1)
result_packed = u_values_packed[:, None, :] ^ v_values_packed[None, :, :]

result_packed = result_packed.reshape((-1, result_packed.shape[2]))
result_unpacked = np.unpackbits(result_packed, axis=1)[:, :u_values.shape[1]]
```

When I performed my real use case, I got this error:

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 959. GiB for an array with shape (2788, 1813, 203769) and data type uint8

How can I achieve this by using less memory?

To clarify the problem, here is my expected output for toy example with dimension (48,10):

```
[[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True  True False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True  True False  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False False  True False False False  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True False False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False  True  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True False  True False False False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
 [False False False  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False  True False  True False False  True False False False]
 [False False  True  True  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False  True False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True False  True  True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False  True False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True False False False False]
 [False False  True False  True False False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True False]
 [False False  True False False False False False False False]
 [False  True  True False False  True  True  True  True False]
 [False False False False  True  True False  True  True False]
 [False False  True  True False False False  True  True False]]
```

Comment: What is the size of the arrays in your actual use case?

Comment: @slothrop As shown in my question: (2788, 1813, 203769) which mean that I have one array with size (2788, 203769) and another one with size (1813, 203769).

Comment: Right, and if I'm understanding your example output [(where inputs of shape (6,10) and (8,10) produce an output of shape (48,10)] you want to XOR every pair of rows together (not every pair of elements), so the final output shape would be (5054644, 203769)?

Comment: @slothrop Absolutely, right. How can I do this efficiently by using less memory?

Comment: Right, so regardless of intermediate steps, your output has about 1 trillion elements. Even bit-packed, that's going to consume about 128GB memory, which will be a struggle on most hardware. You probably need to create the output in chunks and write it to disk rather than keeping everything in memory at once.

Comment: You could look at doing something with a memory-mapped array for the output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803/working-with-big-data-in-python-and-numpy-not-enough-ram-how-to-save-partial-r

Comment: @slothrop Can you propose a solution code for this?

Comment: I don't have time for a full solution, but broadly here's an idea. (1) Create the output as an empty memory-mapped array of the right size. (2) Iterate over chunks of rows in `arr1`, using code like you wrote in your question to multiply a chunk of rows by the whole of `arr2`. Write each result to the appropriate rows of the output array. By tuning the chunk size you should be able to fit this to your available RAM.

Answer (score -6):

Performing XOR between every element of two 2D NumPy arrays while efficiently managing memory can be achieved by using the **numpy.bitwise_xor** function and iterating through the arrays in chunks. This can help avoid loading the entire arrays into memory at once, especially for large arrays. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```html
import numpy as np

def xor_arrays_efficiently(arr1, arr2, chunk_size=1000):
    rows, cols = arr1.shape
    result = np.empty((rows, cols), dtype=arr1.dtype)

    for i in range(0, rows, chunk_size):
        chunk_end = min(i + chunk_size, rows)

        # Load a chunk of rows from both arrays
        chunk_arr1 = arr1[i:chunk_end, :]
        chunk_arr2 = arr2[i:chunk_end, :]

        # Perform XOR on the chunk
        result[i:chunk_end, :] = np.bitwise_xor(chunk_arr1, chunk_arr2)

    return result

# Example usage
array1 = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
array2 = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]])

result = xor_arrays_efficiently(array1, array2)
print(result)
```

In this example, the chunk_size parameter determines how many rows are processed at a time. You may need to adjust this value based on your available memory and the size of your arrays. This approach can help minimize memory usage by working with chunks of the arrays rather than loading the entire arrays into memory at once.

Comment: I felt like you used ChatGPT.

Comment: This isn't the calculation the OP is looking for. This only XORs corresponding rows together (i.e. `arr1[456]` is XORd with `arr2[456]`). But the requirement is to XOR every pair of rows (i.e. `arr1[456]` gets XORd with every row of `arr2`).

Comment: This appears to be ChatGPT plagiarism. The OP is presumably posting here because they want a *human* answer.